# Set the color of an instance in kivy language

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I would like to know if there is any way to set the color of the circle's instances in .kv file?

My .kv file:

```
<Circle>:
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
<MyClass>:
    circle1: _circle1
    circle2: _circle2

    Circle:
        id: _circle1
        size: 250,250
        center_x: self.parent.width / 4
        center_y: self.parent.height / 2

    Circle:
        id: _circle2
        size: 250,250
        center_x: self.parent.width * 3/4
        center_y: self.parent.height / 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using **Color**. [Go here](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.instructions.html) to read more on canvas.

You can use canvas.before, canvas.after, with self.canvas and some other ways as per your need.

Just keep in mind that it takes values from `0-1` and not from `0-255`.
So if you have value between 0-255 then just divide it by 255 and use it.

```
   <Circle>: 
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: .2,.5,.5,1
            Ellipse::   
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
```

Here's [colorpicker.py](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/colorpicker.py) on github for color choices.